# SQL запрос на удаление i-й по счёту записи из таблицы БД

Tags: sql, ms-access

Знаю, что у записей в таблице нет такого понятия, как порядковый номер, но стоит задача написать SQL запрос на удаление именно i-й записи независимо от её id или каких-либо других параметров.. Есть ли способы осуществить это?
Upd1: К примеру третью запись в таблице в изначальной сортировке, т.е. в том порядке, в котором записи добавлялись в таблицу. Но id при этом может быть различным, не обязательно отличающимся на единицу у соседних записей.

Comment: что такое i-й по счёту? В какой сортировке?

Comment: В любом случае, я бы свёл задачу к `delete from where id = (select)`

Comment: Да, понимаю, самый простой вариант, но в моём случае id не обязательно идут по порядку, а запрос должен в любом случае удалять именно третью(пятую/десятую) запись, без оглядки на данные и id в частности..

Comment: Какая разница, какие там данные, задача меняется с "удалить запись№i" на "Выбрать запись№i", которую, можно сделать через offset/fetch или top/offset

Comment: Удаляйте _любую_ запись. А потом уверяйте, что именно она была i-той при данном расположении звёзд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если id уникален, удаляем 4-ю запись в порядке возрастания id:

```
delete from table
where id=(select min(id) from table
where id not in
(SELECT top 3 id
FROM table
order by id)) 
;
```

Comment: В конечном итоге остановился на вашем варианте, но от оставшейся части брал только верхнюю запись и так же удалял на основании равенства id. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так:

```
DECLARE @I INT

    SELECT @I = 3

    create table #MyTest (id int, name varchar(3))

    insert #MyTest
    values
    (1,'A'),
    (3,'B'),
    (5,'C'),
    (7,'D');

    WITH CTE (ID,NUM,RN)
    AS
    (SELECT
    ID,NAME,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (ID))
    FROM 
    #MyTest)

    DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN = @I

    SELECT * FROM #MyTest

    DROP TABLE #MyTest
```

Comment: на ms-access думаете будет работать???

Comment: @SergeNazarenko метка появилась после моего ответа(

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать функцию [DCOUNT](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A4%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-DCount-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-227efeeb-5bb3-4343-8277-a0750daf3496):

```
DELETE FROM [MyTable]
WHERE DCOUNT("[ID]","[MyTable]","[ID]<=" & [ID]) = <номер записи>
```

Хотя, автору вроде как не надо привязываться к ID записи, да и вообще ни к какому полю. То есть удалить просто i-ю запись в выборке без каких либо условий сортировки. Не могу даже предположить зачем это надо, тем более без сортировки, но тогда ответ:

> Удаляйте любую запись. А потом уверяйте, что именно она была i-той при данном расположении звёзд. – Alexander Petrov

уже кажется разумным. )

Comment: Когда это может пригодиться на практике - сам даже не представляю, просто наш преподаватель по базам данных в университете - тот ещё выдумщик, с каждой лабораторной удивляет всё больше)